# Django url.py syntax error

Tags: python, django

I am getting the following error and I can't figure out whats wrong with the syntax.

```
Traceback:
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  89.                     response = middleware_method(request)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/middleware/common.py" in process_request
  67.             if (not urlresolvers.is_valid_path(request.path_info, urlconf) and
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in is_valid_path
  531.         resolve(path, urlconf)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in resolve
  420.     return get_resolver(urlconf).resolve(path)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in resolve
  298.             for pattern in self.url_patterns:
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in url_patterns
  328.         patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in urlconf_module
  323.             self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py" in import_module
  35.     __import__(name)
File "/Users/nir/Documents/candycode/wsgi/openshift/../openshift/urls.py" in <module>
  18.     url(r'^contact/', include('openshift.contactapplication.urls')),
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/conf/urls/__init__.py" in include
  24.         urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py" in import_module
 35.     __import__(name)

Exception Type: SyntaxError at /contact/addcontact
Exception Value: invalid syntax (urls.py, line 15)
```

This is my main urls.py and I am attempting to link it to another urls.py inside contactapplication app folder:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',

url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
url(r'^$', 'openshift.views.home_view'),
url(r'^contact/', include('openshift.contactapplication.urls')), <- points here

#for nir's local development purposes
url(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
    {'document_root': '/Users/nir/documents/candycode/wsgi/static', 'show_indexes': True}),
)
```

what could be causing this syntax error? The syntax seems to be correct from my end.

Edit:
This is my contactapplication/urls.py -

```
#contactapplication urls.py 

from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()


urlpatterns = patterns('',

    url(r'^addcontact$', 'openshift.contactapplication.views.contactus_page',
)
```

Comment: What does openshift/contactapplication/urls.py look like?

Comment: urlpatterns = patterns('',

    url(r'^addcontact$', 'openshift.contactapplication.views.contactus_page',
) . I also added the full to my OP

Comment: you forgot parentheses in your contactapplication/urls.py -> `url(r'^addcontact$', 'openshift.contactapplication.views.contactus_page'),`